# using cell caching after creating the .xlsx file

Tags: phpexcel

I have one .xlsx file having 20 sheets in the file,  size is approx 500kb.
while created the .xlsx file i did not used any caching method so my worksheets are created using  'cache_in_memory'.

I am running out of memory now(my server has approx 500mb ram).
Can I cache the worksheets' cells to disk when the memory is not available?
I read in the documentation that after creating the worksheet you cant change the caching method..

Please help me..i want to use disk when the memory is not available to php script..please tell me is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Caching isn't a feature of the Excel workbook, but of PHPExcel. Just because you created a workbook once without cell caching, doesn't mean you can't enable it when you read that workbook again.

You need to enable cell caching before either loading the workbook, or instantiating a new workbook within your script.